# Use Complete Induction of set theory to prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \sqrt{n}$.

Tags: induction

Proove by the Complete Induction for every $n\in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 1$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > \sqrt{n}$$.

I know only the basis - $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} \geq \sqrt{1}$.

But, I dont know how to do the change from the regular induction to the induction of Set theroy(Complete Induction).

Comment: What is the induction of set theory as opposed to regular induction ?

Comment: So you must show that if $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>\sqrt{n}$ then $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n+1}$. That is, you must show that $\sqrt{n}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the induction of set theory but the inductive step for ordinary induction goes like this:

Assume

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}>\sqrt{n}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}>\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}>\sqrt{n+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n+1}
\end{equation}

Thus
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n+1}
\end{equation}